# contador de quantas vezes o programa foi executado em C

Tags: c

queria um programa que contasse quantas vezes foi executado através de um arquivo txt que quarda esse valor, porém o que ocorre é que nunca sai de 1,
alguem tem uma ideia do que fiz errado?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int numero_de_execucoes;
    FILE *total;
    numero_de_execucoes = 0;
    total = fopen("total.txt", "w+");

    if(total){
        while(!feof(total)){
            fscanf(total , "%d", &numero_de_execucoes);//lendo o ultimo numero_de_execucoes
        }
    }
    else{
        printf("ERRO");
    }

    numero_de_execucoes += 1;//incrementando + 1


    fprintf(total, "%d", numero_de_execucoes);//escrevendo no arquivo o 
                                              //numero_de_execucoes atual 

    fclose(total);
    printf("%d",numero_de_execucoes);//saida
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Olhando a documentação do `fopen`:

> "w+"  write/update: Create an empty file and open it for update (both
>   for input and output). If a file with the same name already exists its
>   contents are discarded and the file is treated as a new empty file.

Desta forma você sempre irá criar um arquivo vazio, e depois irá colocar informações nele (no caso seu contador com 1).

Sugiro você alterar sua implementação para utilizar algo como `fopen("total.txt", "r+");`, segundo a documentação:

> "r+"  read/update: Open a file for update (both for input and output).
>   The file must exist.

Você só deve garantir que o arquivo exista, o arquivo será aberto e seu conteúdo será atualizado.

Referência [aqui](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/)